# How to bring the cross to the centre

Tags: node-editor

I am a beginner. Please tell me how do I bring where X and Y cross to the centre of screen. I can bring by zooming in but when i do that this is what happens. It is supposed to be a circle but missing in between (I found how to cure that problem, thanks to one of you)

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information (including a screenshot). In its current form it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

in object mode click shift S and choose 3d cursor to centre